# Problem with sending video using python telegram libraries

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, pyrogram

I've sent this videos using python libraries (first with pyrogram, second with telethon but I've sent them as a client) and I got this

[image: screenshot of videos using telegram web]

(smaller videos are sent properly)

My friends say that they cant see them as well (I can watch and download them on phone though there is also said that this video is 0:00 long)

I want videos to be sent properly

Comment: Telegram will handle videos under 10 MB on its own, adding metadata like duration and resolution. Above this threshold, you'll have to supply this information yourself when using Pyrogram's `app.send_video()`.

Comment: Same as above applies to telethon's [send_file](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file), you're the one responsible of the media encoding and thumbnail extraction, other metadata is handled by the library as mentioned in the docs, but not thumb generation, use the `thumb` param and pass it a dimentionally valid thumbnail of the video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash, password="", phone_number="") as app:
        app.send_video(chat_id=channel_id, 
video=video_path, 
progress=progress_callback, 
duration=duration, 
width=width, 
height=height, 
supports_streaming=True,
 caption="ihatethis",
 thumb=thumb_pic)
        app.close()`
I've tried with async func but its not working, it has my widt, height and duration but no thumb pic and i cannot watch it